# Changing masking policy without unsetting that masking policy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-data-masking

Is it possible to alter an existing masking policy without unsetting this policy?

For example, I have a masking policy that is set to multiple columns. So, when I want to change the policy to include more roles, I have to first unset the policy from every column (which takes a lot of time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes  - just run an ALTER MASKING POLICY... [command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-masking-policy.html#alter-masking-policy)

Comment: ...as long as the data type of the masking policy output doesn't change.